# Python pickling keep object identity

Tags: python, python-3.x, identity, pickle

Is there any way to preserve the identity of a pickled object, i.e. have the below print `True`:

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    pass

x = Foo()
print(x is pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x)))          #False
```

I am using cPickle and cpython 3.x on a Linux box, don't need something that's portable.

Comment: No, the identity is the identity of a particular instance.

Comment: @Cameron, I need this because I have objects with cached properties, with the cache being a dictionary that I store as an attribute of the object (with the object itself as the key to the dictionary). This all works fine. However, when I pickle the object, send it somewhere, and then unpickle it, I now have a new object with the old object ids saved in the keys of the cache dictionary. This cached property is a general factory and I'd prefer not to mess around with the `__eq__` `__ne__` methods. Not sure if the `__getstate__`, `__setstate__` methods are the way to go?

Comment: I think is compares the memory locations of the objects... so it will likely never result in true ...

Comment: When you send the object somewhere, do you also send the cache?

Comment: yes, exactly, i send the cache too - trying to rework using the id for the keys since it doesn't sound like preserving the identity is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, it is possible; You'll need to include the "identity" in the pickled result some how; the most natural being to use `__getnewargs__` and have a `__new__` method return the existing, cached instance in that case.

```
import uuid
import weakref


class Foo(object):
    ident_cache = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, identity=None, **kwargs):
        if identity is None:
            identity = uuid.uuid1()
        try:
            self = cls.ident_cache[identity]
        except KeyError:
            self = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
            self.__identity = identity
            self.__init__(**kwargs)
            cls.ident_cache[identity] = self
        return self

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (self.__identity,)

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
```

```
>>> import pickle
>>> a = Foo(foo=1)
>>> b = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
>>> a is b
True
```

The important note is that you *must* use protocol version 2 (or higher, hypothetically); because otherwise, `__new__` is never called.  This is only a concern on `pickle.dumps`, `loads` doesn't care.

Comment: This does not make sense. Why would I want to pickle in the case? Saving the object persistently basically means that I want to reconstruct it when the process is stopped, and later started again (launching the program). Or I want to send the result of pickling somewhere else in the network. In such situation, I can hardly be sure to get the same unique identity -- at least in the mostly used implementation where the identity of the object is actually the address where it is located.

Comment: An example of when this would be useful is when an object is mentioned in a pickle passed from process "a" to process "b", and later process "b" passes some information back to "a" which mentions the object it got from "a",  in this case, it is desirable for "a" to see the object as the one it originally created instead of a new, otherwise identical object.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually answering the question instead of going with the "why would you possibly want to do this?" response! This is super helpful, even two years later :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    _id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = Foo._id_counter
        Foo._id_counter += 1

x = Foo()
print(x._id==pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x))._id)     # True
```

Comment: how does this preserve object *identity*,  this fails the requirement of `x is pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x))`, this is just preserving an attribute called "_id"